# The angular momentum of zero mass limit of Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

The Kerr metric in Boyer coordinates is
$$
ds^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{2GMr}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right) dt^2 +
       \left(\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}{r^2-2GMr+a^2}\right) dr^2 +
    \left(r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)\right) d\theta^2 
  + \left(r^2+a^2+\frac{2GMra^2}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right)\sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 -
    \left(\frac{4GMra\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}\right) d\phi dt,
$$
where the $a$ is angular momentum per unit mass.
In the zero mass limit, it becomes
$$
ds^2 = - dt^2 +
       \left(\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)}{r^2+a^2}\right) dr^2 +
    \left(r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)\right) d\theta^2 
  +
    \left(r^2+a^2\right)\sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2. 
$$
The interesting thing is that there are some $a$ left, and it seems they are infinity.

My question is, is there any physical meaning for the $a$ left, or is it just a parameter?

Comment: *there are some $a$ left, and it seems they are infinity* Are you saying that $a=\infty$? How did you conclude that?

Comment: @Ghoster I mean, if you keep $J$ to be finite and choose $m \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The Kerr metric describes a rotating body. $a = J/Mc$ is the angular momentum per unit mass of the body. $a$ characterizes the rate of rotation.

In the limit $M \rightarrow 0$, the metric becomes the orthogonal metric for oblate spheroidal coordinates. These are useful for when the boundary conditions are an oblate spheroid. This is the shape you would expect a small rotating body to take.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems the physical parameter becomes a pure mathematical parameter in this limit. Could you still explain a as angular momentum in this zero mass limit?

Comment: @DavidXiao:  $a$ is angular momentum *per mass*.  If $M \to 0$ and $a$ remains finite then $J \to 0$ automatically in this limit.

Comment: If the size of the object that is rotating is truly $0$, how is this different from flat space? What value of $a$ would you use to describe a rotating object of identically $0$ size? If $J$ and $M$ are both exactly $0$, $a$ is indeterminate. The problem becomes non-physical.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You mean the precondition we could write down a meaningful zero mass limit is we also take $J \rightarrow 0$, otherwise, we will not get a sensible metric?

Comment: @DavidXiao:  Basically, yes.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert But another question arise if you do so, if you set $J=0$, what's the value of a, 0 or arbitrary?

Comment: @DavidXiao:  If you set $J = 0$ while holding $M \neq 0$ constant, then $a = 0$ and you get back Schwarzschild.  But that's a different sort of limit than when you take $J \to 0$ and $M \to 0$ simultaneously, which is what you're doing if you assume that $M \to 0$ while $a \not\to 0$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I just think you actually have two metrics, one is the flat metric written oblate spheroidal coordinates, and the other is the zero mass limit of Kerr metric, in the zero mass limit of Kerr metric, the $a$ parameter is actually $J/M$, which is undefined. Physically, we think the zero $J$ and zero $M$ is flat, so we identify these two metrics, but I don't think it's a trivial thing.